# Sending data to an iOS device

Tags: php, ios, sql, client-server

I need some pro advice.

I'm working on an iPhone app that sends and receives a reasonable amount of data for one HTTP round trip.

1. The device sends a POST request to the server
2. The server responds with the data needed for the device

Initially the server was sending XML back to the device, where the device parsed it and stored it within its sqlite3 database. But I've been thinking... why do I need to encode the data within XML, break it apart, then write a query client-side to store the data. Why can't I use the server to write the queries, and simply execute them on the device?

There may be a security threat here, perhaps, and I would love to hear what exactly that may be, but I'm not convinced that I absolutely need to encode the data in XML; unless I was building an API of some sort.

Anyways, I've been thinking about this problem for quite some time (I'm still very new to programming) and I would absolutely love some expert advice on this.

Thank you for your time,

Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a couple of options for data transmission:

1) For security you can use SSL via NSURLConnection.

2) You can use JSON instead on XML. Take a look at NSJSONSerialization.

3) Or depending on your server side and app needs, you could just send plain HTML (text).

It's kinda hard to give you more detailed input without knowing some specifics of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Oh wow, JSON is much easier to implement then XML. NSXMLParser is intense, multi-threaded yes, but intense. That's great thank you for your answer. Yeah, and I think I'm going to SSL encrypt the connection, the app is starting to feel naked and that's unsettling.... Thanks for the help!